# Django DRF - add a sub view/url?

Tags: django, django-rest-framework

I want to create a subview (if this is the right term?) under a view that alters the query set for example

```
parent URL
mysite.com/api/sites

Child URL
mystic.com/apit/sites/open
```

and also each one of those URLS could be searched so

```
parent URL
mysite.com/api/sites/search=London

Child URL
mystic.com/api/sites/open/search=London
```

my parent View, serializer, and URL already exists

```
class SiteROView(viewsets.ReadOnlyModelViewSet):
    queryset = Site.objects.all()
    serializer_class = SiteSerializer
    permission_classes = (IsAdminUser,)
    filter_class = Site
    filter_backends = (filters.SearchFilter,)
    search_fields = ('location','postcode','state')
```

so I think I need to somehow add the suburl to that

```
class SiteROView(viewsets.ReadOnlyModelViewSet):
    queryset = Site.objects.all()
    serializer_class = SiteSerializer
    permission_classes = (IsAdminUser,)
    filter_class = Site
    filter_backends = (filters.SearchFilter,)
    search_fields = ('location','postcode','state')

    def url_open:
        queryset = Site.objects.filter(state='open')
```

Is this possible, and how would I achieve it?

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do that by using detail_route decorator

```
from rest_framework.response import Response

class SiteROView(viewsets.ReadOnlyModelViewSet):
    ..........
    # your codes up here

    @list_route(methods=['get'],url_path='open' permission_classes=[YourPermissionClass])
    def open(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
         # your rest of code and response
         queryset = <your_filtered_queryset>
         serializer = self.serializer_class(queryset, many=True)
         return Response(data=serializer.data)
```

Comment: so I've added the new query set, how do I return that as a httpresonse?

Comment: Do you want httpresponse or JsonResponse(standard DRF response)? Because httpresponse does not make sense here.

Comment: yes the json response, I just saw an error for httpresonse when I just returned the query set that was all

Comment: You have to serialize the data before passing to reponse. I've updated the code.

Comment: thank you! that works, however I did get the below notice list_route` is deprecated and will be removed in 3.10 in favor of `action`, which accepts a `detail` bool. Use `@action(detail=False)` instead.